# To find the probability of largest face coming up on a die

Tags: probability

Suppose that a 6-sided die is rolled $n$ times. Let $X_i$ be the value of the top face at the $i$th roll,
and let $X\triangleq\max_{1\le i\le n} X_i$ be the highest value observed. For example, if $n=3$ and the three
rolls are 4, 1, and 4, then $X_1=4, X_2=1, X_3=4$ and $X=4$.

To find the distribution of $X$, observe first that $X\le x$ iff $X_i\le x$ for all $1\le i\le n$,
hence $P(X\le x)=(x/6)^n$. It follows that $P(X=x)=P(X\le x)-P(X\le x-1)=(x/6)^n-((x-1)/6)^n$.
For example, $P(X=1)=(1/6)^n$, and $P(X=2)=(1/3)^n-(1/6)^n$.

In this problem we assume that each of the n dice has a potentially different number of faces, denoted fi, and ask you to write a function largest_face that determines the probability P(x) that the highest top face observed is x.

In this problem we assume that each of the $n$ dice has a potentially different number of faces, denoted $f_i$,
and ask you to write a function **largest_face** that determines the probability $P(x)$ that the highest top face observed is $x$. **largest_face** takes a vector $\boldsymbol f$ of positive integers, interpreted as the number of faces of each of the dice, and a value $x$ and returns $P(x)$. For example, if $\boldsymbol f=[2, 5, 7]$, then three dice are rolled, and $P(1)=(1/2)\cdot(1/5)\cdot(1/7)$ as all dice must be 1, while $P(7)=1/7$ as the third die must turn up 7.

I did the same calculation for $\boldsymbol{f}=\left[2,5,7,3\right]$ with $x=3$, but I am not getting the correct answer. According to me the answer should be $\left(\dfrac{1}{5}\right)\left(\dfrac{1}{7}\right)\left(\dfrac{1}{3}\right)=0.009372$, but its not correct. Where am I wrong?

P.s.- I don't need the programing part, just want to understand the logic.

Comment: Please use MathJax to improve the readability of your post.

Comment: See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/ please.

Answer (score 0):

Note that

\begin{align}
P(X = 3) &= P(X \le 3) - P(X \le2)\\
&= \prod_{i=2}^4P(X_i \le 3) - \prod_{i=2}^4P(X_i \le 2)
\end{align}

I don't think it is $\frac15 \cdot \frac17 \cdot \frac13$.